# Finding a parametric form for the locus of points for a vanishing determinant

Tags: quadratics, plane-curves, curves, parametrization

I need to find the locus of points in the real $(x, y)$ plane, in parametric form, satisfied by the equation

\begin{equation}\det\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & c_1 & y & c_2\\
1 & c_1 & 0 & c_3 & x  \\
1 & y & c_3 & 0 & c_4 \\
1 & c_2 & x & c_4 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} = 0\,,
\end{equation}
for $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ and $c_4$ real and positive semidefinite constants.

This equation is quadratic in $x$ (and also in $y$).  The locus of points usually comes in three pieces.  But if the largest of the constant $c_4$ satisfies $\sqrt{c_4} > \sqrt{c_1} + \sqrt{c_2} + \sqrt{c_1}$ there is a fourth piece.

**Question**: How do I obtain the four parametric equations $(x(t), y(t))$ with each one describing a single piece for a given choice of $c_i$'s.

The picture below illustrates a case with four pieces (I obtained this by solving the above quadratic equation for y in terms of x and plotted the two solutions).

[image]

---

I tried all sorts of transformations, but couldn't get a nice clean form for the curves.  Because of the clean and symmetric form of the equation, I really believe there is a solution to this problem.  Would anyone know?

Comment: What is the (4D? hypervolume? lines ?) geometric quantity you are defining? As its vanishing determinant could represent a tangential / coincidental situation.

Comment: what do you mean by positive semi definite constants!? Do you mean that $c_i \ge 0$? :)

Comment: @H.R. Yes, positive definite means non-negative.  Maybe I should have used that.

Comment: The determinant, as a function of $x$ and $y$, is continuous on $\Bbb R ^2$. The locus that you are looking for is the preimage of the closed set $\{ 0 \}$ through this continuous function, therefore it must be *closed* in $\Bbb R ^2$. Why do say say, then, that the "locus of points usually comes in three *open* sets"?

Comment: @AlexM. Well, I only *assumed* them to be open based on looking at sample graphs.  The three V-shaped curves look like open sets to me, and the small O-shaped curve looks closed.  I have no formal training in maths beyond multivariable calculus.  Perhaps you can enlighten me as to how the three disconnected pieces are actually closed?

Comment: @QuantumDot: It's a basic theorem in general topology that the preimage of a closed (respectively: open) set through a continuous map is closed (respectively: open). Combine this with my previous comment.

Comment: @AlexM. I see.  So I am going to edit this and replace "three open sets" with "three disconnected sets".  Would that be better?  Also, would the whole "topology/preimage" stuff going to be helpful for getting my parametric equations?

Comment: @QuantumDot: No, this won't help with your problem, sorry. "Disconnected" might be ok, in any case better that "open" (which was simply not true).

Comment: I believe those curves generally are elliptic curves, so they don't have parametrisations with rational functions.

Comment: @Narasimham I just realized this determinant is proportional to the volume of a tetrahedron of sides $x$, $y$, $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$, $c_4$.  (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html)  Would that help?

Answer (score 1):

When I simplified the determinant using MAPLE, I got something like

$$\eqalign{
  & -{1 \over 2}\det A =   {x^2}y + x{y^2} - \left( {{c_1} + {c_2} + {c_3} + {c_4}} \right)xy  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, + \left( {{c_2} - {c_4}} \right)\left( {{c_1} - {c_3}} \right)x + \left( {{c_3} - {c_4}} \right)\left( {{c_1} - {c_2}} \right)y  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, + \left( {{c_1} - {c_2} - {c_3} + {c_4}} \right)\left( {{c_1}{c_4} - {c_3}{c_2}} \right)  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = P(x,y) \cr} \tag{1}$$

**Observations**

$1.$ A nice re-statement of your problem is to find parametric equations for the family of curves

$$Q(x,y)=x^2y+xy^2+axy+bx+cy+d=0\tag{2}$$

where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are arbitrary real constants.

$2.$ I think that form $(1)$ is the best that you can have since any parameterization may need different cases to consider. You can just see the equation

$$P(x,y)=0\tag{3}$$

as the implicit equation of your curves and it contains all of them in just one equation!

$3.$ You can solve for $y$ from $(2)$ to obtain some explicit equations in the form $y=f(x)$. However, you should discuss the sign of the discriminant $\Delta$ of the quadratic equation for the existence of real roots which will be frustrating since $\Delta=\Delta(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,x)$!

$4.$ Another important point is that there are in fact just **two** explicit formulas $y_i=f_i(x), i=1,2$ for the curves not **three** or **four**! One for the $\color{blue}{\text{Blue}}$ part and one for the $\color{red}{\text{Red}}$ part. Those parts that you see nothing are the parts that for the given values of $c_i$'s and $x$, there is no real root for the quadratic equation. To be more specific, in those parts

$$\Delta(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,x) \lt 0 \tag{4}$$

$5.$ There are some cases that we have real roots for all values of $x$. The following picture shows the case $c_1=c_4=0$ and $c_2=-c_3=-5$. In this case, we have

$$\begin{array}{}
P(x,y)=x^2y+xy^2+25x+25y=0 \\
xy(y+x)+25(y+x)=0 \\
(y+x)(xy+25)=0 \\
y=-x \\
y=\frac{-25}{x}
\end{array}$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but I don't want an implicit equation to describe three (or four) disconnected subsets.  The reason is that the explicit solutions have branches that break up the separate sets in a yucky way (as you can see in the plot).  I would like three parametric equations, each one of the form $(x(t), y(t))$ to describe the entirety of each disconnected piece.

Comment: You said in your question that "I'd like a parametric form $(x(t),y(t))$ for all four sets for a given choice of $c_i$'s" so I thought you want just **one** parametric equation for all the curves! However, the only way to go through is to consider the No. $3$ in my answer. :)

Comment: See my No. $4$ comment in the updated answer. :)

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear: so here's a baby problem to which I have an adequate solution.  Consider the locus of points satsfied by $x^2+y^2-1=0$.  According to your No. 4, this gives explicit formulas for two curves: $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$.  This is exactly what I want to avoid.  The solution I am looking for is $(x(t), y(t)) = (\cos t, \sin t)$.  This is one parametric equation describing the single set of points.

Comment: @QuantumDot: In my opinion, You cannot achieve such a parameterization for this problem! :) I am saying this when I just take a look at equation $(1)$!

Comment: I see, thanks!  Would you kindly remove your answer and add just this opinion as a comment under my question?

Comment: @QuantumDot: Nope! :) It took me some time to write down these things and I don't want to feel wasting my time! :) Of course, you can flag my answer as low quality and if the other users agree with you then it will be removed automatically. :)